# How to wait for a process to finish in Windows?

Tags: windows, multithreading

I have to process running in windows. The second one should wait until the first process exits in order to start processing. I want something like the pthread_cond_wait so that my second process is inactive until it receives a signal saying that the first process is gone.

I remember once I found the answer, a quite simple windows API call, but I cannot remember it.

Comment: WaitForSingleObject()?

Comment: Yes, can you write that in the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).